# Python: When outputting a list to a csv, each row element has strange spacing added

Tags: python, csv

I have finally got my python program outputting what I want into each cell of row 1 of a csv, however weird tabbing or spacing occurs after each item

Here is the segment of code in question:

```
def createvars(filename, count, varlist):       # Appends each suffix to each variable
    varsuffix = list()
    newvarlist = list()
    iterations = 0

    os.system('cls')
    print 'Variable Creation\n-----------------'
    print 'Selected file: ', filename + '\n'

    try:
        iterations = input('How many iterations of the variables do you need?: ')
    except NameError:   
        print 'Please enter an interger value greater than 0'
        os.system('pause')
        createvars(filename, count, varlist)
    for i in range(iterations):
        varsuffix.append(raw_input('Variable Suffix ' + str(i+1) + ': '))
    newvarlist = ['{}_{}'.format(a, b) for b in varsuffix for a in varlist]

    writecsv(filename, newvarlist)

def writecsv(filename, newvarlist):             # Writes to selected CSV file
    with open(filename+'_output.csv', 'wb') as writefile:
    if writefile.closed:
        print 'ERROR: Failed to open file'
        os.system('pause')
        menu(0)
    contentsWrite = csv.writer(writefile, dialect='excel', delimiter='  ')
    contentsWrite.writerows(newvarlist)
    writefile.close
    print 'File saved as: ' + filename + '_output.csv'
```

Here is what I mean about weird spacing in the output file:

[image]

Comment: Why are you writing a flat list of strings with `writer.writerows()`? That Excel actually managed to produce something meaningful from this is quite miraculous, actually.

Comment: *Aside*: 1) You do not need to check `writefile.closed`, it will never be `True` immediately following `open()`. According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), "*If the file cannot be opened, IOError is raised.*". 2) If you want to close the file, you can call `writefile.close()`, not `writefile.close` (`.close`, withtout the parens, does nothing). 3) You don't need to close the file. It will be closed automatically as soon as the `with` indentation block is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the delimiter to be a double space:

```
contentsWrite = csv.writer(writefile, dialect='excel', delimiter='  ')
```

For Excel, don't set the delimiter, or use the [`excel-tab` dialect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.excel_tab) if you require tabs instead of commas.

You also should not use `writer.writerows()` with a flat list; each *character* is written as an individual column. At best, if you wanted each element in `newvarlist` to be a separate row, produce separate lists for each row with just the one column:

```
contentsWrite.writerows([col] for col in newvarlist)
```

Comment: I get a _csv error:


  File "variables.py", line 112, in writecsv
    contentsWrite = csv.writer(writefile, dialect='excel_tab')
_csv.Error: unknown dialect`

Comment: @RussellE: the object is named `csv.excel_tab`; if you are using the string name, then use `'excel-tab'` with a dash.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake. What would you suggest instead of using writer.writerows() for a flat list?

Comment: @RussellE: It's fine to use `writerows()` but make sure you pass in a sequence of lists. How you produce those lists doesn't matter all that much, I used a generator expression here.